# Verification of linear mapping definitions based on linear maps defined on a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Exercise.**

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional with $2 \leq \text{dim}V \leq \text{dim}W$. Show that $\{T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W) : T \text{ is not injective}\}$ is not a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$.

**What I've tried.**

Denoting $\{T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W) : T \text{ is not injective}\}$ as set $A$, I want to show that there exist two linear maps $T_1, T_2 \in A$ such that $T_1 + T_2 \notin A$. This would show that $A$ is not closed under addition, which is enough to show that it is not a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$. To show that $T_1 + T_2 \notin A$ is to show that $T_1 + T_2$ is injective, that is $\text{null}(T_1+T_2) = \{0\}$.

Let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_m\}$ be a basis of $V$ and let $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ be a basis for $W$.

**Question.**

Can I define $T_1 \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ by

$$
T_1(a_1v_1+ \cdots + a_mv_m) = a_1w_1 + \cdots + a_{n-1}w_{n-1}
$$

and define $T_2 \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ by

$$
T_2(a_1v_1+ \cdots + a_mv_m) = a_nw_n
$$

based on the following lemma:

[image]

If I can, are these transformations not injective to begin with? If I cannot, is it because the assumption in the exercise is that $\text{dim}V \leq \text{dim}W$? I'm concerned my linear maps are implying that $m \geq n$.

Comment: There are no coefficients $a_n$ and (possibly) $a_{n-1}$ since your assumption is $m \leq n$.

Comment: @azif00, thank you, that's what I thought. What's a general strategy for coming up with linear mappings to show existence? Is it trial and error until I get the ones that satisfy the criteria I want?

Comment: If you replace $n-1$,$n$ in the definition of $T_1$,$T_2$ by $m-1$ and $m$ the idea will work,

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Thank you! I think I got it; I posted my solution as an answer. If you could review it, that would be awesome. If not, no big deal. I don't justify every step, but what I don't justify was already proves or shown in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $2 \leq m \leq n$ by assumption, your bases look as:
\begin{align}
v_1 && v_2 && \cdots && v_m \\
w_1 && w_2 && \cdots && w_m && \cdots && w_n
\end{align}
Consider the unique linear map $T \colon V \to W$ that sends $v_1$ to $0$ and $v_j$ to $w_j$ for $j=2,\dots,m$, and consider the unique linear map $U \colon V \to W$ that sends $v_1$ to $v_1$ and $v_j$ to $0$ for $j=2,\dots,m$.

Since $T$ and $U$ have nonzero nullspaces, $T$ and $U$ are not injective.

But, as $T+U$ sends $v_j$ to $w_j$ for $j=1,\dots,m$, $T+U$ is injective (why?).

Comment: Thanks! We have slightly different definitions for our two linear maps, but I think my solution follows the same path as yours.

Comment: @PaulAsh Oh, you're right. I hadn't noticed that with those subscripts. But yes, they are basically the same linear maps.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution.**

Thanks to the comments, I was able to figure out where I went wrong. Let's instead define $T_1\in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ by

$$
T_1(a_1v_1+ \cdots + a_mv_m) = a_1w_1 + \cdots + a_{m-1}w_{m-1}
$$

and define $T_2 \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$ by

$$
T_2(a_1v_1+ \cdots + a_mv_m) = a_mw_m
$$

where $w_1, \ldots, w_m \in \{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$, the basis of $W$.

Let's first show that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are indeed not injective. We have that $T_1(v_m)=0$ and $T_1(0)=0$, but $v_m \neq 0$ since it's in the linearly independent list $v_1, \ldots, v_m$. Thus, $T_1$ is not injective and so $T_1 \in A$. Likewise, $T_2(v_j)=0$ for $j=1, \ldots, m-1$ and $T_2(0)=0$, but $v_j \neq 0$. Thus, $T_2 \in A$.

We can now consider $T_1 + T_2$. For any $v \in V$ we have

$$\begin{aligned}
(T_1 + T_2)(v) &= T_1v + T_2v \\ &= T_1(a_1v_1+ \cdots + a_mv_m) + T_2(a_1v_1+ \cdots + a_mv_m) \\ &= (a_1w_1 + \cdots + a_{m-1}w_{m-1}) + (a_mw_m) \\ &= a_1w_1 + \cdots a_mw_m
\end{aligned}$$

We want to show $T_1 + T_2$ is injective. Well, by the equation above, we can consider

$$
(T_1 + T_2)(a_1v_1+ \cdots + a_mv_m) = a_1w_1 + \cdots a_mw_m = 0
$$

Since $\{w_1, \ldots, w_n\}$ is a basis of $W$, the set is linearly independent. But we know that removing vectors from this set will retain the set's linear independence, that is, $\{w_1, \ldots, w_m\}$ is linearly independent. This implies $a_1 = \cdots = a_m = 0$ is the only solution to the above equation. But that means that $a_1v_1+ \cdots + a_mv_m = 0$, implying $v = 0$ is the only solution to $(T_1 + T_2)(v) = 0$, which further implies $\text{null}(T_1 + T_2) = \{0\}$. This means that $T_1 + T_2$ is injective, and so, $T_1 + T_2 \notin A$, showing that $A$ is not closed under addition. Thus, $A = \{T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W): T \text{ is not injective} \}$ is not a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$.